# Implementing a k-d tree for 'nearest neighbor' search in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, multidimensional-array, nearest-neighbor, kdtree

I am designing an automated trading software for the foreign exchange market. 
In a MYSQL database I have years of market data at five-minute intervals. I have 4 different metrics for this data alongside the price and time.

```
[Time|Price|M1|M2|M3|M4] 
x ~400,0000
```

`Time` is the primary key, and `M1` through `M4` are different metrics (such as standard deviation or slope of a moving average).

Here is a real **example** (excerpt:)

```
+------------+--------+-----------+--------+-----------+-----------+
|  Time      | Price  |     M1    |   M2   |    M3     |     M4    |
+------------+--------+-----------+--------+-----------+-----------+
| 1105410300 | 1.3101 |   12.9132 | 0.4647 |   29.6703 |        50 |
| 1105410600 | 1.3103 |    14.056 | 0.5305 | 29.230801 |        50 |
| 1105410900 | 1.3105 |   15.3613 | 0.5722 |   26.8132 |        25 |
| 1105411200 | 1.3106 | 16.627501 | 0.4433 | 24.395599 |  26.47059 |
| 1105411500 | 1.3112 |   18.7843 | 1.0019 | 24.505501 |    34.375 |
| 1105411800 | 1.3111 |   19.8375 | 0.5626 |        20 |   32.8125 |
| 1105412100 | 1.3105 |   20.0168 | 0.6718 |    9.7802 |   23.4375 |
| 1105412400 | 1.3105 |   20.4538 | 0.8943 |     7.033 |   23.4375 |
| 1105412700 | 1.3109 |   21.6078 | 0.4902 |   11.7582 |   29.6875 |
| 1105413000 | 1.3104 |   21.2045 |  1.565 |    8.6813 |    21.875 |
+------------+--------+-----------+--------+-----------+-----------+...400k more
```

Given an input of `M1`, `M2`, `M3`, and `M4` I want (quickly and accurately) find the 5,000 closest matches.

**Sample input:**

```
+------------+--------+-----------+--------+-----------+-----------+
|  Time      | Price  |     M1    |   M2   |    M3     |     M4    |
+------------+--------+-----------+--------+-----------+-----------+
| 1205413000 | 1.4212 |   20.1045 | 1.0012 |    9.1013 |    11.575 |
+------------+--------+-----------+--------+-----------+-----------+
```

I figured that each of these metrics could be considered a 'dimension,' and that I can do a `nearest neighbor search` to locate the closest datapoints in this multidimensional space.

It seems the simplest way to do this is to iterate through every single data point and measure the multidimensional distance to my input point; but speed is of the essence!

I read about something called `K-D Trees` used for this purpose. Can anyone please explain or provide me with some material that explains how to implement this in MYSQL?

It may be relevant to mention that I can pre-process the table, but the input is received in real-time.

Currently I just make a rough cluster around the data on each dimension independently:

```
INSERT INTO Dim1 SELECT * FROM myTable AS myTable USE INDEX(M1) WHERE myTable.M1 < currentM1 ORDER BY M1 DESC LIMIT 2500;
INSERT INTO Dim1 SELECT * FROM myTable AS myTable USE INDEX(M1) WHERE myTable.M1 > currentM1 ORDER BY M1  ASC LIMIT 2500;

INSERT INTO Dim2 SELECT * FROM myTable AS myTable USE INDEX(M2) WHERE myTable.M2 < currentM2 ORDER BY M2 DESC LIMIT 2500;
INSERT INTO Dim2 SELECT * FROM myTable AS myTable USE INDEX(M2) WHERE myTable.M2 > currentM2 ORDER BY M2  ASC LIMIT 2500;

INSERT INTO Dim3 SELECT * FROM myTable AS myTable USE INDEX(M3) WHERE myTable.M3 < currentM3 ORDER BY M3 DESC LIMIT 2500;
INSERT INTO Dim3 SELECT * FROM myTable AS myTable USE INDEX(M3) WHERE myTable.M3 > currentM3 ORDER BY M3  ASC LIMIT 2500;

INSERT INTO Dim4 SELECT * FROM myTable AS myTable USE INDEX(M4) WHERE myTable.M4 < currentM4 ORDER BY M4 DESC LIMIT 2500;
INSERT INTO Dim4 SELECT * FROM myTable AS myTable USE INDEX(M4) WHERE myTable.M4 > currentM4 ORDER BY M4  ASC LIMIT 2500;
```

**It is important to understand that I am interested in distance by rank, not by value.**

**Edit:** I am a little closer to understanding how to do it (I think):
I need to pre-process each row of each metric and assign it a `percentile` which would represent its location (percent-wise) in its range.

For example, for any given value of `M1`:

```
percentile = (#  rows with values less than input)/(# total rows)
```

If I calculate the input's percentile and use *that* for a nearest neighbor search instead of the actual value I will have effectively scaled the various metrics such that they could be used as dimensions.

I am still lost on how to do the actual search though. Is this even possible to accomplish efficiently in MySQL?

Comment: You say the search input is of `M1`, `M2`, `M3`, and `M4`, but your sample includes `Time` and `Price`. Are they included in the "closest" matches? How are you going to define close? The scale of `M4` vs `M2` for example is pretty big, so I don't think you necessarily want to search in a spherical manner...

Comment: @jswolf19 `Time` and `Price` are not included in the search. I want to define "close" by "number of `events` away from the input" - where each row in my main table is an `event`. Perhaps the dimensions need to be scaled first?

Comment: Say the input for `M2` is 2 and the input for `M4` is 30. Would `Time`=1105413000 be closer or would `Time`=1105412400 be closer?

Comment: It may be a good idea to add columns for normalized data so that the "closeness" is comparable in the different dimensions. Will you be adding new data to insert into the table as the searches are performed?

Comment: @jswolf  Is it really necessary to add new columns? Can't I just use the median or something like that instead?  I intend to add new data, not literary AS the search is performed, but immediately after each time.

Comment: You're concerned about speed but calculating the median is ok? ^_^ You might be able to get away with simply dividing by the max, I guess, but that's your call and they're just numbers to me, so I don't know what they mean (not that I'm a statistician and knowing what the numbers are would help me much, anyway ^^). I'm thinking your best bet is to set a sphere/ellipse in your search space and adjust it in a binary search fashion until you get as close to 5000 records as possible. Are you using a MySQL version that allows stored procedures?

Comment: @jswolf19 Well, I have 400k+ rows in my table. I mentioned something like using the median because I can pre-calculate it. I would like it to be exactly 5000 records. Additionally, the distribution of these metrics are all different, so I cannot use any shape (sphere/ellipse/etc) to find them.

Comment: Actually - I realized that I COULD expand spherically if I just did it by rank instead of by actual value! Can you please show me how to expand spherically across 4 dimensions in MySQL?

Comment: I don't think you're always going to be able to get exactly 5000 records using the actual values (and rank will be even harder, I imagine) unless you figure out how to handle tie breakers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do a query like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE M1 BETWEEN searchM1 - radiusM1 AND searchM1 + radiusM1
  AND M2 BETWEEN searchM2 - radiusM2 AND searchM2 + radiusM2
  AND M3 BETWEEN searchM3 - radiusM3 AND searchM3 + radiusM3
  AND M4 BETWEEN searchM4 - radiusM4 AND searchM4 + radiusM4
```

In the case of a sphere, all the `radius` values will be the same, of course. You then adjust the radius until you get as close to the number of records you want. I'd suggest a [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

I'm not sure if you want to mess with the distribution or not, but assuming you do, you would just need to give each search value a rank between the two values it would fall between in your table (e.g. if rank 5 is 5.5, rank 6 is 5.9, and the search value is 5.6, then the search rank could be 5.5)

Comment: he's looking at closest points. THere could be millions of data within that interval. It's inefficient to compute all distance for all data.

Comment: @JimThio, if you have an idea of how to do what the OP wants efficiently using mysql, then you're more than welcome to provide an answer for them.

Comment: actually your answer is good enough for mysql. Mysql can't do efficient nearest neighbor search. I am looking for a better wya.

Comment: @jswolf19: it's a curse of dimensionality once you have more metrics: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality - there is no efficient solution in MySQL. "It is not possible to quickly reject candidates by using the difference in one coordinate as a lower bound for a distance based on all the dimensions." A solution is to either do the lookup yourselves in KD tree, or use database that supports NN operations, like Postgres: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11015922/indexing-k-d-tree