# Indexing k-d tree?

Tags: mysql, kdtree

I need to index a k-d tree, and be able to match part of it later.
Is MySQL capable of ? Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try PostgreSQL 9.1.It can support Nearest Neighbor Search Indexes

http://excoventures.com/talks/knn.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I answer myself: current database can't index and search kd-tree.

Comment: could 2d spatial indexes be used for 3d-trees?

Comment: Sometimes the answer is "there is no solution". Thank you for posting; saves me some searching.